# Change content of div when clicking on link/button

Tags: php, jquery, html

Basically I have a web page that has a div id="content" and a div id="sidebar",

What I would like to do is change the content in the content div when a link/button is clicked in the sidebar without having a serperate page for each article.

The reason being;

I am doing a BIO page for some multiple bands and there would be multiple buttons for each band then when a user clicks the button/link the content would change.

Any idea's, I have been looking into .click using jQuery or maybe PHP but not exactly sure on how to implement it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put each of the articles in one HTML file on your server, each with a div wrapped around it, like this (let's say the file is called myArticles.html and is in the same folder as your main page):

```
<div id='article1'>
    <b>ARTICLE 1</b> This is my first article
</div>

<div id='article2'>
    <b>ARTICLE 2</b> This is my second article
</div>
```

Then use jQuery's `.load` function to load this data using AJAX into your page.

Say your button for article 1 has the id = 'articleButton1' and 2 has id = 'articleButton2' (and both with href='#', so the page doesn't change) then this jQuery  would work:

```
$('#articleButton1').click(function(){
    $('#content').load('myArticles.html #article1');
}

$('#articleButton2').click(function(){
    $('#content').load('myArticles.html #article2');
}
```

This picks the correct div out of that page on your server and puts it into the `#content` div

Comment: "Say your button for article 1 has the id = 'articleButton1' and 2 has id = 'articleButton1' ". Both have same id's? Shouldn't the .click be in "articleButton1" instead of on the article div?

Comment: thanks, alot for the reply. I have got a working implementation based upon your suggesting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to look into this tutorial,

[Tabify](http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/)

Answer (score 1):

what about jQuery UI vertical tabs?
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html

more on jQuery UI tabs and loading content via ajax:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax