# Dynamic div change with using jQuery not working on my site

Tags: php, jquery, html

I tried many type of codes but neither worked. Last one that I tried is this : [Change content of div when clicking on link/button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916411/change-content-of-div-when-clicking-on-link-button)

I have 2 buttons that need to execute script. One is to get dynamic content on page that is not working. Second is to logout of site and that one is working.

Here is part of my main page code :

```
<?php

echo '<p></p>';
echo '<p></p>';

echo '<div style="width:300px;float:left;">';

    echo '<button type="buton" id="loyaltybut" onclick="loyalty()" style="background:#8C8C8C;width:300px;margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:7px;" href="#">But1</button>';
    echo '<button type="buton" id="logoutbut" onclick="logout()" style="background:#8C8C8C;width:300px;margin:1px auto;">But2</button>';

    #Loyalty report - script
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'function loyalty() {';                        
                echo '$("#loyaltybut").click(function(){';
                echo '$("#data").load("localhost/data #article1");';
                echo '}';
                echo '}';                       
        echo '</script>';

        #Logout - script
        echo '<script>';
            echo 'function logout() {';
            echo 'window.location.replace("localhost/logout/");';
            echo '}';
        echo '</script>';

        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div id="data" style="width:750px;float:right;">';

        echo '</div>';?>
```

My data script :

```
<?php

echo '<div id="article1">';
echo '<b>ARTICLE 1</b> This is my first article';
echo '</div>';

?>
```

What can I do to make it work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you output html and script like that? It doesn't contain any PHP calculations. Also `type=buton` should be `type=button`.

Comment: Actually it have PHP calculations. This is only part that I'm trying to do with, but I have to connect it to database, check if everyting ok, etc... I changed buton - button, still no luck

Answer (score -2):

To Work with Jquery you have to import jquery.js

```html
<script src="http://www.mneye.com/scripts/jquery172.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Using this URL to import your JavaScript is very ill-advised. The URL links to a privately owned site with the jQuery library on it. This file could be modified at any point by the owner and introduce security concerns to the script. Please get your jQuery from [here](http://jquery.com/download/) or another reputable CDN...

Comment: Imported this one <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>. Still no luck